# How to monitor the C-states of an Intel (Core 2 Duo) processor?

Tags: cpu-usage, intel

I am studying the effects user usage on the power consumption. How do I measure the C-state occupancy in Intel Core 2 Duo processor (Windows 7)? Is there a software which can do this in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Intel does provide [a number of tools and guidelines](http://software.intel.com/en-us/energy-efficient-software) for power, and [power-checker](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-power-checker-to-measure-the-energy-performance-of-a-compute-intensive) in particular lists "Core based processors" as supported, and C-state occupancy as one of the features.